# CleanWebpackPlugin with devServer Not Rebuilding dist Folder, Thus Breaking Sourcemap

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code

I am using `Visual Studio Code (VSC)` with `Webpack`, `devServer` and the `CleanWebpackPlugin`.

When running the `buildd` script the `dist` folder is deleted then rebuilt again with the new files, as it should. When running `devServer` however, the `dist` folder is deleted but not rebuilt.

This causes an issue, seeing how `webRoot` in `launch.json` is supposed to let the debug agent in VSC know where to look for source files and sourcemaps. When the `dist` folder is deleted, it can't find those files. This can be verified by looking at the `.scripts` command in the debug console.

As seen below, the sourcemaps map correctly to the sources, but the top line is missing the connection between the server and the file it serves. When I remove the CleanWebpackPlugin, it works (see `.script` output at the very bottom).

**RELEVANT FILES**

---

**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/scripts/app.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'],{

        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Production'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "styles/[name].css"
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'scripts/[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [{
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    }, {
                        loader: "postcss-loader"
                    }, {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }],
                    // use style-loader in development
                    fallback: "style-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(csv|tsv)$/,
                use: [
                    'csv-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.xml$/,
                use: [
                    'xml-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        compress: false,
        port: 8080
    }
});
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/dist/scripts",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///*": "${workspaceRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mywebapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "\"My first Webapp\"",
  "main": "./src/scripts/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "buildd": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js",
    "buildp": "webpack -p --config webpack.prod.js",
    "watch": "webpack --progress --watch --config webpack.dev.js",
    "startd": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "startp": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.prod.js",
    "hts": "http-server ./dist",
    "compile": "babel src --out-dir dist --source-maps --watch",
    "sass": "sass --watch src/styles:dist/styles"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "webapp"
  ],
  "author": "MRG",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.34",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.34",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.9",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

**.scripts output when it does not work (i.e with CleanWebpackPlugin). See top line missing the parenthesis, showing the lack of connection)**

```
› extensions::app
› http://localhost:8080/scripts/app.bundle.js
    - webpack:///webpack/bootstrap a59d0d75ae8a9271e6c6 (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\webpack\bootstrap a59d0d75ae8a9271e6c6)
    - webpack:///(webpack)/buildin/global.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\(webpack)\buildin\global.js)
    - webpack:///(webpack)/buildin/module.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\(webpack)\buildin\module.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/html-entities/lib/html5-entities.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\html-entities\lib\html5-entities.js)
    - webpack:///(webpack)-dev-server/client (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\(webpack)-dev-server\client)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/url/url.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\url\url.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/punycode/punycode.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/url/util.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\url\util.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\querystring-es3\index.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/querystring-es3/decode.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\querystring-es3\decode.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/querystring-es3/encode.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\querystring-es3\encode.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\ansi-regex\index.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\loglevel\lib\loglevel.js)
    - webpack:///(webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\(webpack)-dev-server\client\socket.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\sockjs-client\dist\sockjs.js)
    - webpack:///(webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\(webpack)-dev-server\client\overlay.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\ansi-html\index.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/html-entities/index.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\html-entities\index.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/html-entities/lib/xml-entities.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\html-entities\lib\xml-entities.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/html-entities/lib/html4-entities.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\html-entities\lib\html4-entities.js)
    - webpack:///(webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\(webpack)\hot nonrecursive ^\log$)
    - webpack:///(webpack)/hot/log.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\(webpack)\hot\log.js)
    - webpack:///(webpack)/hot/emitter.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\(webpack)\hot\emitter.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/events/events.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\events\events.js)
    - webpack:///./src/scripts/app.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\src\scripts\app.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js)
    - webpack:///./src/scripts/print.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\src\scripts\print.js)
```

**.script output without CleanWebpackPlugin (Works. See top line)**

```
› extensions::app
› http://localhost:8080/scripts/app.bundle.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\dist\scripts\app.bundle.js)
    - webpack:///webpack/bootstrap beb4052598d0b44b1967 (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\webpack\bootstrap beb4052598d0b44b1967)
    - webpack:///./src/scripts/app.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\src\scripts\app.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/process/browser.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\process\browser.js)
    - webpack:///./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js)
    - webpack:///(webpack)/buildin/global.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\(webpack)\buildin\global.js)
    - webpack:///(webpack)/buildin/module.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\(webpack)\buildin\module.js)
    - webpack:///./src/styles/style.scss (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\src\styles\style.scss)
    - webpack:///./src/scripts/print.js (c:\Users\magnusga\Downloads\Programming\TestPrograms\myWebapp\src\scripts\print.js)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am new to Webpack.

When I read through webpack github issues, I figured that webpack-dev-server will not write to disk, but will run plugin. So here comes your problem,  CleanWebpackPlugin got called, but nothing write in to disk, and this seems like it never rebuild. Have this in mind we can rearrange the code.

Also, this is another thing important, we need to use --hot --inline with script not in webpack.config.js [Github issue here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1151#issuecomment-111972680)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yeo. I actually know more or less how this works now. Dev server does not write to disk because the files are not read / served from there. They are residing in a virtual server on localhost. Thus, having a dist folder on the drive would be misleading. Also, my initial remark about the source map paths was wrong. It needs to map from localhost to src files, and the `launch.json` setup for that is not as complex as I initially thought.